# Scala - Sum multidimensional array

Tags: scala, multidimensional-array, sum

In Scala, this is how I sum the `Int` values of a multidimensional array:

```scala
val data = Array.ofDim[Int](200, 200, 200)
// fill data with Int values

val sum = data.map(i => i.map(j => j.sum).sum).sum
```

Is there a shorter, perhaps easier to read, way of getting the sum of the array?

Comment: Consider asking on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). That aside, consider a function for flattening the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good solution would be:

```
val sum = data.flatten.flatten.sum
```